# Where can I post quests I've written online for others to use and benefit from?

Tags: adventure-writing

I've written a few quests now and documented them fairly thoroughly. Are there any places online where I can share them so that others would be able to review and use them if they needed to? It would be great if there was a place where people could share their quests so they could grab one quickly if they needed to and allow others to do the same with those they've written. Do any sites like this exist for sharing of quests?

Comment: Are those quests set in a specific published game world?  I assume not otherwise there would be a game tag but worth checking nonetheless.

Comment: @Sardathrion You're correct, they are not in a specific published world.

Comment: You should consider accepting answers on your questions: Pick the one that worked best for you.

Answer (score 6):

[RPG.net](http://www.rpg.net/) has a [wiki](http://wiki.rpg.net/index.php/Main_Page) that includes two areas that you might post such adventures.

1. There is a [listing](http://wiki.rpg.net/index.php/Free_Adventures) of various free adventures to be found on the internet.  This is useful if you want to post the adventure on your site, but get a large community linked into finding it.
2. There is a separate [listing](http://wiki.rpg.net/index.php/Short_Adventures) for short adventures hosted directly on the site.  It is thin in respect to what is available, but other areas are more fleshed out, so I assume it is from the lack of writers of such adventures and/or interest in creating them.

In general, it seems that there are quite a few places that host new games and settings created by fans, but not so much in the way of adventures.

Answer (score 4):

Stuffer Shack is set up specifically for posting Adventure Ideas, Encounter Ideas, Character Ideas, and so on.  [Here is a link](http://stuffershack.com/category/steal-this/steal-this-adventure/) for some examples of Adventure Ideas. Once you begin posting your adventures, you can set up a profile page (if you want), and even get some free items from our Store as a thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[RPG now](http://www.rpgnow.com/) could be a good place.  Release the work under [CC](http://creativecommons.org/) and you can charge nothing for it -- or call it charity ware or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

**Obsidian Portal**

http://www.obsidianportal.com/

Obsidian is a platform where you can share your work with others. In the first place it is meant to keep track of **CAMPAIGN** stuff, for GM and partymembers, but it can be made public. On your Campaign pages there is room for a Wiki, Adventure Log, Character related material, Items descriptions, Maps, etc… and also Comments.

They also have a **FORUM** (with a 'review my campaign' sticky) and **BLOG**.

So most of the essentials to organize peer-review and sharing of campaigns is at hand. You can see how popular a certain campaign is by the number of 'fans' it has, but there is no real rating, which is a downside if you want to use it as resource to pull material from. If there exist sites which concentrate purely on the 'post a campaign, review it and rate it' that may be more what you are looking for.